# How to add cradit card payments to android app if Google Pay is not available in your country?

Tags: android, mobile-application, google-pay

Is there any other way where I could add credit card payment to my app since Google Pay is not yet available in my country? I want the experience to be in-app not taking a user to a payment gateway via a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stripe (https://stripe.com), is easy to implement and has a native SDK for android.

Android doc: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test out the Google Pay experience by using the following steps:

1. Join the [`googlepay-test-mode-stub-data` Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data) - this will allow you to access stubbed payment methods while testing. If you no longer want this behavior, leave the group.
2. Click on `TEST` Google Pay button integration - [demo site](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos) available. I'm not 100% sure if it works with an Android integration, but maybe you can let us know if it does.